# How to match umlaute (äöü) in regular expressions when they have different byte representation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

So I have a weir issue. I have files on S3 and I want to match words against the filename, using a regular expression. The regular expression should clearly match, but it does not:

```
irb(main):048:0> p.original_filename
=> "Küche.png"
irb(main):049:0> "Küche.png"
=> "Küche.png"
irb(main):013:0> reg = /(\A|\W|\d|_)#{Regexp.quote("Küche")}(\W|\z|\d|_)/i
=> /(\A|\W|\d|_)Küche(\W|\z|\d|_)/i
irb(main):014:0> reg.match?("Küche.png")
=> true
irb(main):015:0> reg.match?(p.original_filename)
=> false
irb(main):050:0> p.original_filename == "Küche.png"
=> false
```

So I inspected further and already assumed, that there is an encoding issue:

```
irb(main):017:0> p.original_filename.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):018:0> "Küche.png".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

That is weird. But let's see what characters and bytes are behind the representation:

```
irb(main):025:0> "Küche.png".chars
=> ["K", "ü", "c", "h", "e", ".", "p", "n", "g"]
irb(main):026:0> p.original_filename.chars
=> ["K", "u", "̈", "c", "h", "e", ".", "p", "n", "g"]
irb(main):032:0> p.original_filename.bytes
=> [75, 117, 204, 136, 99, 104, 101, 46, 112, 110, 103]
irb(main):033:0> "Küche.png".bytes
=> [75, 195, 188, 99, 104, 101, 46, 112, 110, 103]
```

So here is the issue. My question: How can I normalize the filename so that it matches with the regexp `/(\A|\W|\d|_)#{Regexp.quote("Küche")}(\W|\z|\d|_)/i` ? I tried `force_encoding` and `encode` without success, since the bytes are different.

Note: It is not an option to only use ASCII characters for the filenames. This has to work with umlaut.

Comment: `p.original_filename.unicode_normalize` should do the trick – it turns `u¨` into `ü`. (if possible, you should normalize the filenames before storing them)

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, that was it!

Comment: Post an answer, @Stefan!

Comment: BTW, this is _not_ a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408402 – that question is about removing diacritics, i.e. converting characters to their closest ASCII equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unicode, certain characters can be represented as a base character and a combining character:

```
"\u0075\u0308" # LATIN SMALL LETTER U (U+0075) + COMBINING DIAERESIS (U+0308)
#=> "ü"
```

or as a single *precomposed* character:

```
"\u00fc"       # LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (U+00FC)
#=> "ü"
```

If you type characters on your keyboard, it will usually generate the  latter.

The process of converting a given string into one of these representations is called *normalization*.

In Ruby, there's [`String#unicode_normalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-unicode_normalize) which defaults to the latter format:

```
a = "\u0075\u0308"
b = "\u00fc"

a.codepoints                   #=> [117, 776]
b.codepoints                   #=> [252]
a.unicode_normalize.codepoints #=> [252]
```

Applied to your example, you'd use:

```
reg.match?(p.original_filename.unicode_normalize)
```